# Cucumber -- Gem Viewcucumber formatter Load error

Tags: ruby, cucumber

I am using this gem for the first time, and after following instructions I get this error:

https://github.com/versapay/viewcumber

```
$ cucumber --format viewcucumber --tags @test
cannot load such file -- viewcucumber (LoadError)
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
```

I am  confused whether to use this as part of cucumber.yml file or do it at commandline or how to use it.  At this stage, I am not able to find an example online.

Has anyone tried this?

Comment: The gem seems like abandonware, with the last commit being 2 years ago. The fact that they released something which generates HTML unable to be viewed in Chrome is a good indicator that it's not so well thought out. A shame, as it's a great idea, hopefully some continued forks or alternatives out there...

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this `cucumber --format Viewcumber featureFiles --tags @test`? I think the only problem is the capital 'V'

Comment: Sorry mate.. just tired it out.. didnt work..:( cucumber --format Viewcumber --tags @login browsertype=firefox26 envtype=PROD
an't modify frozen String (RuntimeError)
://Software/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.3.15/lib/cucumber/cli/configuration.rb:185:in `rescue in block in formatters'
://Software/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.3.15